# flash ubuntu touch on nexus 4 hangs

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I have tried to follow [this guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) and flash Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4. After I run:

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

but the tool hangs like this:

```
2016/03/30 19:14:09 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
2016/03/30 19:14:09 Device is |mako|
2016/03/30 19:14:10 Flashing version 28 from ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-28.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-e7bded45d0d16151d514bd048425082697ce175825afad15c0ec8c31d0d7ea98.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-d9a1f38a50139f3bd81a94d5f223ede533c376220120d0d984e70db9718cbcb6.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-5f4806a2d26af9d26279d1e66d217281dfa19219a85d2fd64999460f47d6efb9.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Done pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-28.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:19 Start pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:20 Done pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/03/30 19:14:20 Done pushing ~/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
```

nothing else happens for hours.
I have tried different recovery tools but nothing changed.
Can I "manually" flash Ubuntu with install zip?

Comment: Having the exact same Problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in a virtual machine...

Answer (score 0):

Just do `ubuntu-device-flash --clean-cache touch` and then try it again.;)

This will clean the cache of the ubuntu-device-flash tool. This causes
the tool to download the whole image again. For me this helped sometimes, when I had problems during flashing my device.

Comment: And what is that command supposed to do exactly? You can give some more explanation of how it works and what it accomplishes.

Comment: See my answer, I edited it. Or look at the man page.

Comment: Dud you had success?

Answer (score 0):

The --bootstrap option is normally **only used when installing Ubuntu the first time**. It requires that the device is booted to the bootloader. After Ubuntu is installed, one uses the ubuntu-device-flash command (without the --bootstrap option) while the device is booted to Ubuntu